# Remove https: from the doi

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biber, texmaker, doi

How can I remove the prefix https:// from the doi? Some of the doi entries in my database is  DOI: 10.1080/15588742.2015 while others are https://doi.org/10.3945/jn.109.117093. I want to keep doi in all the loaded references in the same format. How can I do it? I'm using texmaker on MAC. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[
12pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, ]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=anyt,url=false,style=bwl-FU,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,firstinits=true,uniquename=false,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\renewcommand*{\doi}{doi: \url}

\addbibresource{Latex_database.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{american-apa}

\begin{document}

This document lists all the references.

\citet{Janetal1997}

\citet{hesst2020}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: well you should learn to make examples that other can run and test. That means provide the bib entries and don't use a class that is not available in texlive/miktex.

Comment: In general, you should only use `10.XXXXXX`  in your `bib` file. The rest is inserted automatically. But it should be possible to take the prefix away with some kind of e.g. RegEx. And what @UlrikeFischer said!

Comment: I see.. thanks. I admit that I'm not that good with Latex and so not aware with the idea textlive/miktex etc.